# Can I power 2x6 socket surge protected PDUs from a surge protected UPS?

Tags: ups, power-distribution-unit, surge-protection

I've got a local network rack with:

- 24 port switch
- 2x voip dect bases
- 2x modems
- 1x load balancing router
- 1x wifi access point
- 1x 2bay Synology nas

At the moment these are all powered via 2x 1U 6 socket surge protected PDUs.

I want to add a UPS into the rack but the ones I was looking at in terms of power / battery output only have 4 power ports on the back. Can I plug the PDUs into the UPS to get around that or would that cause an issue?

The reason I ask is because I've heard that if you daisy chain 2 surge protected extension cords you negate the surge protection, so I was wondering if I plugged the PDU into the UPS if it would have a similar effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use surge protected PDUs. Instead, use a plain, quality PDU without surge protection.

This is [recommended by APC](http://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA158852/). Also, [read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/34883/8280) for some nice background explanation.